# C Preprocessor #if handling of non-integer constant

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have the following code snippet to allow me flip easily between double and float representations of floating point values:

```
#define FLOATINGPOINTSIZE 64

#if FLOATINGPOINTSIZE == 64
typedef double FP_TYPE;
#define FP_LIT_SUFFIX 
#else
typedef float FP_TYPE;
#define FP_LIT_SUFFIX f
#endif
```

At another location I had written the following:

```
/* set floating point limits used when initialising values that will be subject
 * to the MIN() MAX() functions
 *
 * uses values from float.h */
#if FP_TYPE == double
#define FPTYPE_MAX DBL_MAX
#define FPTYPE_MIN DBL_MIN
#else
#define FPTYPE_MAX FLT_MAX
#define FPTYPE_MIN FLT_MIN
#endif
```

whereas I think I should have written:

```
#if FLOATINGPOINTSIZE == 64
```

I have `-Wall` compiler setting to give me plenty of warnings but this didn't get flagged up as an issue. Possibly `-Wall` is completely independent of the preprocessor though?

My question is how is the preprocessor interpreting:

```
#if FP_TYPE == double
```

The meaning is obvious to the programmer, but I'm not sure what the preprocessor makes of it?

Its got to be a bug right?

Comment: Try -Wextra and -Wpedantic also.

Comment: `FP_TYPE` is not a macro, it's a typedef. You should use `#if FLOATINGPOINTSIZE == 64` because `FLOATINGPOINTSIZE` is a macro

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I have -Wall compiler setting to give me plenty of warnings but this
>   didn't get flagged up as an issue.

The code is valid, but you are right to be concerned.

> My question is how is the
>   preprocessor interpreting:
>
> ```
> #if FP_TYPE == double
> ```

Good question.

> The meaning is obvious to the programmer, but I'm not sure what the
>   preprocessor makes of it?

The *intended* meaning seems obvious, and as the code's author, you know what you meant.  But what you appear to have intended indeed is not how the preprocessor interprets that conditional.

The expression in a preprocessor conditional is interpreted as an integer constant expression.  Just like in a C `if` statement, if the expression evaluates to 0 then the condition is considered false, and otherwise it is considered true.  All macros in the expression are expanded before it is evaluated, and **any remaining identifiers are replaced with 0**.  Details are presented in [section 6.10.1 of the standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.1).

Supposing that there is no in-scope defnition of a macro named either `FP_TYPE` or `double` (and a `typedef` is *not* a macro definition), your conditional is equivalent to

```
#if 0 == 0
```

, which is always true.

> Its got to be a bug right?

The preprocessing result will not be what you intended, so it's a bug in your code.  The compiler, on the other hand, is correct to accept it.

Comment: that is a superb answer - i had an inkling that that might be the case hence the mention of non integer constant in the OP title

Answer (score 3):

> The meaning is obvious to the programmer, but I'm not sure what the preprocessor makes of it?
>
> Its got to be a bug right?

It's a bug from a user's point of view but it is not a bug in the preprocessor.

```
#if FP_TYPE == double
```

is interpreted as

```
#if 0 == 0
```

since neither `FP_TYPE` nor `double` is a known symbol for the pre-processor.

From https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/If.html#If:

> Identifiers that are not macros, which are all considered to be the number zero. This allows you to write `#if MACRO` instead of `#ifdef MACRO`, if you know that `MACRO`, when defined, will always have a nonzero value. Function-like macros used without their function call parentheses are also treated as zero.

Comment: yes - i was absolutely not implying a problem with the preprocessor or compiler but a bug of my own creation.. I must have slipped into english instead of C - it was still valid code but with a completely different meaning to that which I intended..

Comment: @bph, I hope you got the answer to *what the preprocessor makes of it?* I imagine that was your main question.

Comment: I did, when you also replace FP_TYPE with 0 the preprocessors understanding of the situation becomes clear, i.e. 0 == 0 so will always equate to True

Comment: @bph, I completely missed that aspect the problem when I wrote my answer but now I see it.

Comment: probably to be more accurate I should say when you understand what substitutions the preprocessor has made then the compilers understanding of the situation becomes clear